# Sort records with an associated field

Tags: sql, sorting, go-gorm

I want to order records with associated records in GORM V2.

I have two structs:

```
type Client struct {
    gorm.Model
    UUID                   uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid"`
    ClientProfile          ClientProfile
}

type ClientProfile struct {
    gorm.Model
    ClientID         uint
    FirstName        string
    LastName         string
}
```

Now, I can load all the records with:

```
db.
    Preload(clause.Associations).
    Find(&clients).
```

How can I now order these records with a field from the `ClientProfile` struct?

I tried without success:

```
db.
    Preload(clause.Associations).
    Order("client_profiles.last_name DESC").
    Find(&clients)
```

This throws the following error:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "client_profiles" (SQLSTATE 42P01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find with Preload queries the `clients` table first, and then queries the `client_profiles` table with the IDs from the first, thus it can't sort the first query by data from the second one.

Since this is a HasOne relationship you can use [Joins Preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Joins-Preloading) which actually does use a single query for both entities. Then you will be able to sort by the related entity's field:

```golang
err := db.
    Model(&Client{}).
    Joins("ClientProfile").
    Order("client_profiles.last_name DESC").
    Find(&clients).
    Error
// handle error
```